# launching app on Nexus 4 fails

Tags: android, nexus-4

I'm writing ICS+ app and it works fine on Nexus S, Nexus Galaxy, Nexus 7, Galaxy Tab, Galaxy S3 and bunch of other devices. Yesterday I got Nexus 4 and the app crashes during the startup.

The stacktrace is below. I looked in the sources (android.view.ViewConfiguration) and what the device tries to do is to get fading marquee resource - here is

```
mFadingMarqueeEnabled = res.getBoolean(
            com.android.internal.R.bool.config_ui_enableFadingMarquee);
```

Does anyone has any idea what might be happening?

```
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapp/myapp.Main}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1110013
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1110013
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.content.res.Resources.getBoolean(Resources.java:796)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.view.ViewConfiguration.<init>(ViewConfiguration.java:301)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:323)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3234)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:420)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:93)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.<init>(PhoneWindow.java:1816)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2585)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2867)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.app.Activity.initActionBar(Activity.java:1861)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.app.Activity.getActionBar(Activity.java:1848)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at myapp.Main.onCreate(Main.java:75)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-04 17:54:09.727: E/AndroidRuntime(16932):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is on line 75 of Main.java?

Comment: I'm getting actionBar (getActionBar one line above in the stacktrace)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the internal resources because it would appear they are not public (and are subject to change).

have a look at [The import com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683411/the-import-com-android-internal-r-cannot-be-resolved) for more information on how you would get it to work the way you want.

Comment: I don't use the internal resources (at least I'm not aware of this). The problem is the FrameLayout is the one which uses this resource, but it is not able to find it ...

Comment: what's on line 75 of Main.java then?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the android framework installed on the LG Nexus 4 lacks `com.android.internal.R.bool.config_ui_enableFadingMarquee`

Comment: Right, but how and how to fix it :)

Comment: you can either use another file or copy that file from the aosp site and bake it in your project. Then just refer to your local file.
The android source can be found here: https://android.googlesource.com/

Comment: Edit okay I realized it is a boolean value you need. Could you explain what this value exactly does / what you need it for. Maybe this would help more.

Comment: That's the problem - I don't need it. As you can see, the ViewGroup(FrameLayout) object needs it.

Comment: Also copying it over is not a correct solution. This resource is supposed to be built-in resource. I shouldn't supply it with my app.