# Android: Split ActionBar real parent height

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-relativelayout

I use the action bar (origin android, not ABS) and position my views relatively on the root layout (`RelativeLayout`). To calculate the relative position on the screen I used the `getParent().getHeight()` / `getParent().getWidth()` methods of my view. With the normal ActionBar it works fine. I get the real height of the parent (Activity height - Actionbar hight, e.g. 690px on the 800px display). But if I use the `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` option and the bottom bar is shown I get the same height of the parent (e.g. again 690px on the 800px screen). So some of my programmatically positioned vies are under the bottom action bar.

How can I get the real height of the parent, without the action bars?

Edit:

I read the parent width and height on the `onWindowFocusChanged` method of the activity.

Comment: Bottom bar (split actionbar) has the same height as main ActionBar(the one at the top). So your parent height is height - 2*ActionBarHeight.

Comment: And how can I detect wether the action bar is splited or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the top and bottom action bar are the same height.  As far as I know, you can not request the size of the action bar programmatically.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12304018/338724) post gives an example of how to set the action bar height with a style so that it is consistent.

To determine whether or not the action bar has been split, you must calculate this manually.  As per [the design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) (near the bottom)

> How many actions will fit in the main action bar? Action bar capacity is controlled by the following rules:
>
> - Action buttons in the main action bar may not occupy more than 50% of the bar's width. Action buttons on bottom action bars can use the entire width.
> - The screen width in density-independent pixels (dp) determine the number of items that will fit in the main action bar:
> - smaller than 360 dp = 2 icons
> - 360-499 dp = 3 icons
> - 500-599 dp = 4 icons
> - 600 dp and larger = 5 icons

Example:
[image: table of examples]

So you want to do something like this.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);

float density  = displayMetrics.density;
// width in dp
float width = (displayMetrics.widthPixels / density);

// I will assume you have 3 action bar icons

if (width < 360) {
    // 2 menu items fit.
    // Calculate action bar height with 2*(actionbar height)
    // to accommodate the bottom action bar.

} else {
    // 3+ menu items fit
    // Calculate action bar height with 1*(actionbar height).
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> And how can I detect wether the action bar is splited or not?

Simple. You use boolean values. By default you'll have a split ActionBar if the screen width is smaller than 400dp. 
There is already one declared(which is the one the ActionBar uses to determine if it is a handset device or a tablet).
If you're targeting Android HC+, then you can access the default ActionBars value:
`android.R.bool.split_action_bar_is_narrow`, if you are using ActionBarSherlock:
`R.bool.abs_split_action_bar_is_narrow`.
Found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/bools.xml) for the default ActionBar, [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/res/values/abs__bools.xml) your ABS.

Now you can access the boolean value like this:

```
boolean isActionBarSplitted = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.split_action_bar);
if(isActionBarSplitted){
      // Parent height - SplitActionBar height
}
else{
     // No Split ActionBar
}
```

Keep in mind, that `android.R.bool.split_action_bar_is_narrow` is an internal resource, so you have to get it working like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683411/the-import-com-android-internal-r-cannot-be-resolved/8683466#8683466).

Comment: Thanks for that link to the android boolean values!  Very good to know.